# generate jenkins api token using rest api

Tags: rest, jenkins

Hello I am using Jenkins API using Basic Auth of ldap. Now, i figured out that the API can be accessed through tokens as well. However these tokens are specific to each jenkins instance, I want to know if there is a way to retrieve these API tokens using REST api calls?

Comment: Well, they are a security measure. Can you clarify, are you asking if theres an api call to get a token of a build by a rest request with basic auth involved?

Comment: i need a rest api to generate the API token of a user so that i can perform create/build jenkins jobs through REST api, yes with Basic Auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this information is not directly available through REST API or `jenkins-cli`, API token could be still extracted using Basic authentication when making a HTTP request.

An example based on `curl` and `bash` tools:

```
curl --silent --basic http://<username>:<password>@<jenkins-url>/me/configure | hxselect '#apiToken' | sed 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1\n/g'
```

ps. HTML output is parsed using `hxselect` from [html-xml-utils](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) and `sed`.

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem, however introduced a new one - parsing html in java. I had this similar HTML ouput issue for creating credentials in jenkins via REST API.